# How to loop a function through groups of data?

Tags: r

I have code that calculate Kaplan-Meier product..

```html
km_mean <- function(x,nd) {
  library(tidyverse)
  
# first remove any missing data
  df <- tibble(x,nd) %>% filter(!is.na(x))
 x <- df %>% pull(x); nd <- df %>% pull(nd)
# handle cases of all detects or all nondetects; in these situations, no Kaplan-Meier
# estimate is possible or necessary; instead treat all detects as actual concentration estimates
# and all NDs as imputed at half their reporting limits
 if (all(nd==0)) return(tibble(mean=mean(x),sd=sd(x)))
 if (all(nd==1)) return(tibble(mean=mean(x/2),sd=sd(x/2)))
# for cases with mixed detects and NDs, table by nd status;
# determine unique x values; first subtract epsilon to each nondetect to associate
# larger rank for detects tied with NDs with same reporting limits
 eps <- 1e-6
 x <- x - nd*eps
 nn <- nlevels(factor(x))
# determine number of at-risk values; build kaplan-meier CDF and survival function;
# note: need to augment and adjust <tab> for calculation below to work correctly
 km.lev <- as.numeric(levels(factor(x)))
 xa <- c(x,max(x)+1); nda <- c(nd,0)
 tab <- table(xa,nda)
 tab[nn+1,1] <- 0
 km.rsk <- cumsum(tab[,1] + tab[,2])
 km.cdf <- rev(cumprod(1 - rev(tab[,1])/rev(km.rsk)))[-1]
 names(km.cdf) <- as.character(km.lev)
 km.surv <- 1 - km.cdf

  km.out <- tibble(km.lev,km.rsk=km.rsk[-length(km.rsk)],km.cdf,km.surv)
  row.names(km.out) <- NULL

# estimate adjusted mean and SD
 xm <- km.lev[1] + sum(diff(km.lev)*km.surv[-length(km.surv)])
  dif <- diff(c(0,km.cdf))
 xsd <- sqrt(sum(dif*(km.lev - xm)^2))
 names(xm) <- NULL; names(xsd) <- NULL
 tibble(mean=xm,sd=xsd)
}
```

My data has three columns, a sample-ID, value (x), and detect/non-detect flag (nd).

```html
a1  0.23 0
a1  2.3 0
a1  1.6 0
a2  3.0 1
a2  3.1 0
a2  2.76  0
```

How can I adapt the function to run on all a1 samples as a group, then a2, etc.?

I've tried group_by commands, but can't seem to break through.

Comment: Hi welcome to SO.  You should check out: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and consider structuring your query as a minimal reproducible example

Comment: If you want to run a function that operates within the `group_by` logic, then either (a) you need to look internally to the `tibble` handed *as a whole* to the function and look at the `"groups"` attribute, or (b) run your function within a `do(...)` block in your `%>%` pipeline.

Comment: How do you know your function works and it does what it is supposed to do? Does it work for any one example ?

Comment: It currently runs through all my data as it should, all sample IDs combined, my goal is for it to do the exact same, but with all the 'a1's, then all 'a2's, etc.

Comment: What have you tried to *adapt the function to run on all a1 samples as a group...*? Show us more of your attempts with the `group_by` commands, and the errors you've faced. People around here can help a lot with problems, but don't like reviewing / completing code...